# A is closed and bounded subset of R. Which of the following exist?

Tags: real-analysis

$\sup A$

$\inf A$

$\max A$

$\min A$

I Thought all of them exist! Since $\sup = \max$ and $\inf = \min$ if it's closed and bounded.

But the answer says otherwise. Why???

Can anyone please help? Thank you.

Comment: The answer you are provided with is wrong! And you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Trick question! The empty set is closed and bounded. (You are right for non-empty sets.)

*Remark*: It is a matter of taste whether the infimum and supremum of the empty set exist. Some people define the infimum to be $\infty$ and the supremum to be $-\infty$ (There is no typo in the previous sentence!) But definitely the max and min of the empty set do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

For a general bounded set $A$, the supremum and infimum exist by the completeness axiom. The example $A=(0,1)$ shows that the max and min need not exist.

In your example, however, since the set it closed it will contain its sup and inf, which will therefore be the max and min of the set. So you are correct.

Comment: Thank you. I really hate typos in the notes..........:( poor me.